# web.py invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, string, web.py

I need to convert a string type, from and get call on web.py, into an integer, but I'm getting this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Here is my code:

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')
urls = ('/webservices/test', 'Test')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input(id="")

        id = int(user_data.id)
        return id



application = app.wsgifunc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I've seen this documentation:

http://webpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/input.html

Comment: Is `user_data.id` a valid string type number?

Comment: yes, I did a verification using the following code: 

if isinstance(id, str):
            return "this is a string"

Comment: What is in `user_data.id`? Your `isinstance(id, str)` verification only says that it's a string, it doesn't say that the string is a valid representation of an integer.

Comment: for instance, the empty string "" is not a valid integer, and since you set user_data.id to that, it's unsurprising that doesn't work, set it to "0" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You give a default constructor of `user_data.id` as `""`.  If this is not specified by the browser, you will be calling

```
int("")
```

which is what is throwing your error.  Try

```
user_data = web.input(id="0")
```